# Python modificar un diccionario que está dentro de una lista

Tags: python, array

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que el usuario inserta un valor y se crea una lista de diccionarios, tantos como se haya dicho. El problema es que no se como cambiar el valor de los diccionarios, ya que son la misma variable.

```
n = int(input('number of elements in the list: '))
lis = []
dic = {'k1': '', 'k2': ''}

for i in range(n):
    lis.append(dic)
```

Comment: Cual es el resultado deseado? una lista de dicccionarios ? o sea [{'k1': ''}, {'k2': ''}] o un diccionario con varios keys {'k1', 'k2', ...}

Comment: Lo que quiero es que el usuario pueda introducir un valor para 'k1' en el elemento 0 de la lista y otro para 'k1' en el elemento 1 de la lista.

Comment: Entiendo pero ese quiere decir que por cada iteración de tu for le pregunte el valor que desea ingresar, correcto? pero no entiendo porque lo guardad en una lista si a través del diccionario tambien podrias recorrerlo o sea quedaria {'k1': 'valor 1', 'k2': 'valor2'} y a este rocorrerlo para su uso. Ahora respondo con codigo

Comment: Lo que quiero es como una lista de la compra, me explico. Quiero que por cada objeto que este en el carrito, pregunte qué es, cuánto cuesta y cuánto vale. Por lo que no sabes a priori cuantos elementos tiene la lista, y por eso quiero acceder al diccionario desde una lista. Me explico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas guardarlo en un diccionario no es necesario guardarlo en una lista ya que a partir del diccionario tambien puedes recorrerlo.

```
n = int(input('number of elements in the list: '))
dic = {} // Aqui lo deje vacio ya que esto se llenara dinamicamente 

for i in range(n):
    // al índice le aumente 1 para que no empiece de 0
    idx = i + 1
    // le pedimos al usuaro el valor para cada valor
    value = str(input('Insert value {}: '.format(idx)))
    // Creamos los nombres de los keys dinamicamente por cada iteracón del for
    key = 'k{}'.format(idx)
    // y por ultimo le pasamos el valor del usuario ingresado a nuestro key
    dic[key] = value
```

Eso es todo pero ahora si quieres recorrer este diccionario... lo hacemos de esta manera:

```
for item in dic.items():
    print(item)
```

Eso es todo :D!

Comment: muchas gracias! Y si le quiero poner un nombre distinto a cada key como seria?

Comment: Ahora si quieres guardarlo en una lista cada diccionario simplemente pon el dic = {} dentro del for y por cada iteracion al dic guardarlo en la lista. tulista.append(dic)

Comment: pero es que lo que quiero es que el diccionario tenga un número de keys concretas y se puedan hacer tantos diccionarios como el usuario quiera

Comment: Ahí le estoy poniendo un nombre distinto a cada key :D fijate en el parte que dice key = 'k{}'.format(idx) :D no te olvides de darle manito arriba jaj

Comment: @IgnacioTejeroLópez muestrame como quieres que sea el formato del resultado

Comment: Voy a explicarlo con el ejemplo de la compra. Lo que quiero es que el usuario diga cuantas cosas ha comprado, y que cada cosa tiene una ''caracteristica'' especial. Ej:[{'nombre': 'queso', 'cantidad': '2', 'precio': '2EUR'}, {'nombre: 'yoghurt', 'cantidad': '4', 'precio': '6EUR' }]

Comment: Y esos precios de donde los sacas? el usuario tambien lo ingresa?

Comment: Si. Lo que ingresa el usuario es el numero de diccionarios que se almacenan en la lista, y los elementos en si.

Comment: ya lo he resuelto muchas gracias!

Comment: Me alegra saber eso :D